# How can I prove this function is bijective?

Tags: functions

I know I have to show it's injective and surjective, but up until now it's always been simple equations that I can prove are equal to each other. This equation is a little bit more complex.

$$f(x) = (x-a)\frac{d-c}{b-a} + c$$

Im $99\%$ sure it's bijective, but I don't know how to prove it since there is nothing to set it equal to like other examples. Also $a \lt b$ and $c \lt d$

Comment: What is the domain and range? It's impossible to answer the question of whether a function is bijective without that information.

Comment: R to R is range and domain

Comment: @user5428151 Please do *not* vandalize posted questions, whether your own or others'. Rolled back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you operate in the set $\mathbb{R}$.

Let's use the abbreviation $m = \frac{d-c}{b-a}$
$$\color{blue}{f(x)} = m(x-a)+c = mx +c-ma \color{blue}{= mx + r} \mbox{ with } r = c-ma \mbox{ and } m>0$$
**Injectivity**:

$f$ is strictly increasing, hence it is injective:
$$x<y \Rightarrow mx+r < my+r \Rightarrow f(x) < f(y)$$
**Surjectivity**:

For each $y \in \mathbb{R}$ you need to find an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = y$:
$$y = mx+r \Rightarrow x=\frac{y-r}{m} \mbox{ is such an }x$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the range and domain are $\mathbb{R}$ (or any field), it's bijective, as is any non-constant linear function; if
$$
f(x) = mx + b
$$
where $m \neq 0$, then
$$
f^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{m}(x - b).
$$

Comment: couldn't m be zero in this case though? since x-a can equal to 0...?

Comment: In your notation, $m = \frac{d-c}{b-a}$ which is constant. To convert to the form $mx + b$ (sorry for reusing $b$) you would have to expand out the first term, collect the coefficient of $x$ for $m$, and collect everything else for $b$.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, the function is continuous assuming the domain being $[a,b]$ and for $x=a\implies f(a)=c$ and $x=b\implies f(b)=d$ again for $x=\frac{a+b}{2}$ we ave $f(\frac{a+b}{2})=\frac{c+d}{2}$. So $f$ assumes every value in $[a,b]$ uniquely in $[c,d]$. Hence it is a bijection. Hope this makes the $1\%$ complete.